# Changing vertical position of characters in a paragraph of text with inline css

Tags: html, css

Can't seem to work out how to change the height of certain letters in a paragraph of text.

http://jsfiddle.net/jposn92b/1/

I've tried padding at the bottom but doesn't seem to change it.

```
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style="padding-bottom:5px;">consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?

</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of options depending on exactly what you want.

1. vertical-align

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style="vertical-align:5px;">consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?
</p>
```

2. position:relative

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style="position:relative;top:-5px;">consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?
</p>
```

The principle difference is that using vertical-align will increase the height of the line box in which the span sits, while using position:relative will not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways you can do this. You could use `<sup>` or `<sub>` tags, but then you have to reset the font size. In the end, it's adjusting the `vertical-align` style.

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <sup style="font-size:1em;">consectetur</sup> adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. <span style="vertical-align:super;">Nisi eius</span> deleniti <span style="vertical-align:sub;">voluptates</span> quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<sup>` tag

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <sup style="padding-bottom:5px;">consectetur</sup> adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?
```

Answer (score 0):

set the position as relative and top = -5px or whatever value you want.

```
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span position:relative; top:-5px;">consectetur</span> 
adipisicing elit.Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. 
    Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni
     eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?
    </p>
```

Comment: This might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <sup style="font-size:1em;">consectetur</sup> adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<span style="vertical-align: 20px;">consectetur</span>` in order to move some parts of the text up.